# First 10 char from $GET parameter from column

Tags: mysql

MYSQL Query How to get first 10 char from $_GET from column customername from mytable.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 'customername'=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])"
```

Which operator to use ? TOP selects rows 
I want to get first 10 characters of all records in column customername.

Comment: what did you try so far? you can cut it on php side after getting query result

Comment: i don't try anything because i don't know what to use.I've read for TOP but it returns rows from query which operator returns letters from column ?

Comment: The mysql-way is to use the substring() function but I am not sure if you are looking for something else here?

Comment: show us more of your php code.

Comment: I'll try something OK.

Comment: I think @stenix pretty much gave it to you. When you say "first 10", keep in mind right now you are getting first 10 physical. Look into `order by` if necessary, and review your index(es). [String functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), look at `left()` and `substring()` etc

Comment: `SELECT *, LEFT(customername,10) as left10 FROM mytable WHERE 'customername'=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])"`